# How to get Integer of BigDecimal without separator

Tags: java, integer, bigdecimal, currency

I got the following BigDecimal from a Money-Object: BigDecimal 49.99 and I need this as Integer 4999, so everything I ask for is getting rid of the separator.

I could get this BigDecimal as String and remove the separator and parse it to an Integer, but I do not think that this is pretty.

```
BigDecimal bigPrice = moneyPrice.getValue();
Integer price = bigPrice.intValue();
```

Using this only responses with 49.

Comment: I can't see any reason why you would want this. 49.99 isn't the same as 499.9

Comment: I need to convert from € to Cents to pass it to another interface. So 49.99 € to 4999 Cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal("49.99");
// multiply with 10^scale ( in your case 2)
db = db.multiply(new BigDecimal(10).pow( db.scale()));
System.out.println(db.intValue());
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought way to complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You need the method:

```
movePointRight(int n)
```

javadoc link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#movePointRight(int)

example:

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("398.0275");
    System.out.println(bd.movePointRight(bd.scale()));
```

outputs:

```
3980275
```

If you want to use the number, just `bd=bd.movePointRight(bd.scale());`

Answer (score 1):

If it's currency and always to 2 dp, you could multiple it by 100. However as Davio comments, your code should make it clear why you're doing it.

If you want to convert, for example a price in GB pounds sterling to GB pence (100 pence in a pound) then multiplying it by 100 is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to do any math on the `BigDecimal`; you can just call `myBigDecimal.unscaledValue()` to get the underlying unscaled `BigInteger` directly.